# Can anyone help me add a Javascript pagination for my datatables

Tags: javascript

My datatable right now has script that filters the name of the table. I'm really hoping that you guys can help me add the pagination script on my current script right now.

I badly need help on this one. Hoping for a response on the additional JS :( thank you so much! I will highly appreciate the help.

JS

```
    function filterBar() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My DataTable

Filter:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 60%;">English</th>
            <th style="width: 40%;">Other Language</th>
            <th style="width: 30%;">Status</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


        Showing <span id="minEntry">0</span> to <span id="maxEntry">0</span>
        of <span id="totalEntries">0</span> entries
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="#" class="previousPage">Newer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="previousPage">&lt;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="currentPage" class="page-number">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nextPage">&gt;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nextPage">Older</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery](https://datatables.net/)?

It is a very simple and easy way to add search and pagination facility in your table.

You just need to add their js and CSS files and call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Visit their website for more help.

Comment: sadly I am not allowed to use Jquery for the pagination and I need it to manually do it in JavaScript. Could you help me on this one. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well don't know why you are not allowed to use jQuery. But it won't be simple to implement pagination with search by hard-coding. I can give you a pure js library to do the same. But in the end it will be the same as adding jQuery as it will also add external files.